# Perl - Trying to use sort method

Tags: perl

I don't know the exact word but this is what I'm trying to achieve in Perl.

I have a variable named `$var`

```
my $var = "10 60 20 70 30 60 30 50 50 40 40 30 40 20 50 10 60";
```

This is a dynamic value. At the moment I predefined it just to make it easy to understand.

then I split `$var`

```
my $var1 (split //, $var);
```

and from this point I dont know what im talking about.

I want to sort `$var1` like this

```
30 40 50 10 20 30 40 50 60 10 20 30 40 50 60 70
```

Is there a way to achieve this result?

I tried researching sort but none of the results I found covered this issue. Normally if I used their method I would get 10 20 30... and so on.

Comment: What's the logic behind your sort requirements?

Comment: i don't really know how to describe this but if  there is a value like 1 2 3 4 4 2 5 3 6 i want to sort this like 4 5 6 (<<incomplete pattern first)1 2 3 4 5 6(<<complete pattern) so it would be like this 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best sense I can make of your question is that you want a hierarchy of lists — each containing all the duplicates from the next list in the sequence. But there are three occurrences of `60` in the input and only two in the output.

This solution works by pushing each value onto the first element of `@groups` that doesn't already contain that value. Once all the items are placed, the array is reversed and each sub-array is sorted in numerical order

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'any';

my $var = "10 60 20 70 30 60 30 50 50 40 40 30 40 20 50 10 60";

my @var = split ' ', $var;

my @groups;

for my $item ( @var ) {
  my $i = 0;
  ++$i while any { $item == $_ } @{ $groups[$i] };
  push @{ $groups[$i] }, $item;
}

@groups = map [ sort { $a <=> $b } @$_ ], reverse @groups;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@groups;
```

**output**

```
[
  [30, 40, 50, 60],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
]
```

Comment: is it possible to format the output to "30 40 50 60 10 20 30 40 50 60 10 20 30 40 50 60 70"

Comment: @WESTKINz: Yes. Yes it is. How determined are you to do this without any effort of your own?

Comment: I'm reading books about Perl and wish i was cleaver like you but this is my first month trying Perl and I'm just experimenting with my thoughts :)

Comment: @WESTKINz: Then you have started at the wrong place

Comment: btw there an error where its says this "any" is not exported by the List::Util module and yes i am working toward output formatting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to put equal values in bins and sort the bins.

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4
5
6
```

Then you read the answer down column, from rightmost column to leftmost column. Try some more examples and let us know.